# how to set vertically scrolling ScrollView withinanother vertically scrolling widget (ListView)

Tags: android, android-listview, scrollview

I am having trouble with a scrolling ListView inside a ScrollView.I have tried the code given bellow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/linlaypromodet"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical" >
       <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/linearlayoutheaderpromo"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="80dp"
           android:orientation="horizontal"
           android:gravity="center_vertical"
           android:background="@drawable/dairam_header2">

           <Button
               android:id="@+id/buttonbackhomepromodet"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:background="@drawable/back_arrow"
               android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"/>


            <RelativeLayout  
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textviewheaderpromodete"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/buttonsharepromodet"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/shareicon" />
                     </RelativeLayout>
       </LinearLayout> <ScrollView
                   android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="0dp"
                   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                   android:layout_below="@+id/buttoncartpromodet"
                   android:layout_weight="2"
                   android:layout_marginTop="5dp" > <LinearLayout 
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:maxHeight="100dp" >

           <com.dairam.viewpager.AutoScrollViewPager
               android:id="@+id/imageView1"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="200dp"
               android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
               android:minHeight="100dp"
               android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

           <RelativeLayout
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
               android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
               android:layout_marginBottom="75dp" >

               <Button
                   android:id="@+id/buttonleftarrow"
                   style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                   android:background="@drawable/arrow_leftgray" />

               <Button
                   android:id="@+id/buttonrightarrow"
                   style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                   android:layout_marginRight="5dp"

                   android:background="@drawable/arrow_rightgray" />
           </RelativeLayout>



       </RelativeLayout> 




                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rellay"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

       <RelativeLayout  android:id="@+id/toplay"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                     android:gravity="center_vertical">
           <Button android:id="@+id/viewbtn"
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="2dp"
                   android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                   android:background="@drawable/dividergray"/>

           <Button
               android:id="@+id/buttoncartpromodet"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
               android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
               android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
               android:background="@drawable/redicon"/>

           <Button
               android:id="@+id/buttonwishlistpromodet"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
               android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
               android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttoncartpromodet"
               android:background="@drawable/greenicon" />

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/textView1"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/buttonwishlistpromodet"
               android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonwishlistpromodet"
               android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
               android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
               android:textColor="#000"/>
           <ScrollView
                   android:id="@+id/scrollViewdesc"
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="0dp"
                   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

                   android:layout_weight="1"
                   android:layout_marginTop="5dp" > <ListView
       android:id="@+id/textViewdescription"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" 
       android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

     >

   </ListView> </ScrollView>


                <Button android:id="@+id/dividerbtm"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/dividergray"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textViewdescription"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>



       </RelativeLayout>





       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/textviewsuggestion"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:text="YOU MAY ALSO LIKE"
           android:textColor="#000"
           android:textSize="20sp" />

       <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
           android:id="@+id/pager"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="100dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
           android:background="#fff" >
       </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

            </LinearLayout>
         </LinearLayout>
       </ScrollView>
        <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="60dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
           android:orientation="vertical" >


           <View android:layout_height="1dp"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:background="@drawable/dividergray"
                 android:layout_marginTop="6dp"/>
           <Button
               android:id="@+id/buttonamntpromodet"
               android:layout_width="100dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
               android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
               android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
               android:textColor="#fff"
               android:background="@drawable/redbox" />

           <Spinner
               android:id="@+id/buttonquantitypromodet"
               android:layout_width="100dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
               android:textColor="#fff"
               android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
               android:gravity="center"
               android:paddingLeft="10dp"
               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
               android:background="@drawable/greybox2" />

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/textView2"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonquantitypromodet"
               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
               android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
               android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
               android:text=" Quantity"
               android:gravity="center"
               android:textColor="#fff"
               android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

       </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing wrong (to my knowledge) is putting the listView inside a ScrollView. ListView by itself is inherantly scrollable, so the scrollview is not necessary.

I've had issues myself in the past where it causes neither to scroll.... perhaps that is your issue.

Also, I don't know if its just how you posted the code but you shouldn't start a layout with a button.... i believe it needs to be set inside a layout tag.

Answer (score 0):

Please Remove Scroll View from above Listview Because Listvie itself scrollable.